# How to access a listBox from another windows form in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I have two forms in my project. One is named formOptions and another is formHome. I have a listBox in formOption named Blacklist. I have a textBox by which I can add text to the "Blacklist" listBox. Now, I want to access the items from "Blacklist" listBox from formHome. I have tried the following approach :

```
private void formHome_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formOptions.Blacklist // as follows 
}
```

But at this point it shows an error that "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'formOptions.Blacklist'.

Now, What can I do to access the listBox?

Comment: You tagged your question WPF but make repeated mentions of “forms”. Are you trying to [access a control on another form in the same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566/)?

Comment: @Dour High Arch, Yes I am. Can you help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168071/how-to-access-a-listview-control-on-another-form) how to make instance of a form (fromOpition) on formHome.

Answer (score 0):

By studying this example code, you can  get help:

```
//this code written in form1
Form2 form2 = new Form2();  //Form2 is my second Form
foreach(Control control in form2.Controls)
{
    if(control.GetType()==typeof(ListBox))  //you can put any typeof object
    {
        ((ListBox)control).Items.Add("HELLO"); 
        break;
    }
}
form2.ShowDialog();
```